# VBA code to import sheets from workbooks contained in a specific folder

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

So, I'm receiving a balance sheet of a coffee shop, at the end of each day. They'll be gathered in a folder, and I want to import them to my main workbook and refresh them daily. But each time I run the macro, the previous data gets duplicated.

(https://hizliresim.com/Gm4baV)

```
Sub GetSheets()
Path = "D:\xx\xx\"
Filename = Dir(Path & "*.xlsx")
Do While Filename <> ""
Workbooks.Open Filename:=Path & Filename, ReadOnly:=True
For Each Sheet In ActiveWorkbook.Sheets
Sheet.Copy After:=ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1)
Next Sheet
Workbooks(Filename).Close
Filename = Dir()
Loop
End Sub
```

How can I exclude previous data, without changing the folder's content?
I don't know much about VBA that's why I need your help folks. 
Thanks in advance.

**Edited :** "If sheet(s) with same name (Sheets are named by their unique day/month/year) can be found in my main workbook already, those shouldn't get coppied" - This is the part that i can't implement in this code above basically."

Comment: Is power query an option?

Comment: Well, I'm really a newbie in this subject, never heard about Power Query before, if it can make it work, ofc! I'll look into that

Comment: You can easily implement it in your code. Just check to see if the sheet already exists before you add it, and if it does you just don't add it again. You say *Sheets are named by their unique day/month/year*, so it should be straightforward to see if it's there already.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
Sub GetSheets()
Path = "D:\xxx\"
Filename = Dir(Path & "*.xlsx")
Do While Filename <> ""
Workbooks.Open Filename:=Path & Filename, ReadOnly:=True
Dim SheetExist As Boolean

For Each Sheet In ActiveWorkbook.Sheets
SheetExist = False

For Each sheetthis In ThisWorkbook.Sheets

If Sheet.Name = sheetthis.Name Then
SheetExist = True
Exit For
End If

Next sheetthis

If SheetExist = False Then
Sheet.Copy After:=ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1)
End If

Next Sheet
Workbooks(Filename).Close
Filename = Dir()
Loop

End Sub
```

I create a boolean which changes if the sheet already exist in your workbook. If the boolean does not change the same worksheet does not exist and get copied.